# jquery datepicker is not working text box is present in controller PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I have a function in controller

public function getCourseDetails() {

```
$this->view->js[] = URL . 'views/manageTeam/js/course.js';

$this->view->getcourses = $this->model->GetassignCourses($_REQUEST['courseid']);


    if (empty($this->view->getcourses)) {
        echo 'Nothing to display';
        exit;
    } else {
        $output = '';
        $output .= '  

      <div class="table-responsive">  
      <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
      <tr>
      <th>#</th>

        <th style=" width: 60%;">  Course Name </th>
           <th style="">  Start Date </th>
              <th style="">  End Date </th>
           <th><input type="checkbox" id="selecctall"/> </th>  
               </tr> </thead> 
';


                $i = 1;
                foreach ($this->view->getcourses as $courses):

                    if ($courses['adm'] == 0) {
                        $checked = '';
                        $clas = "";
                    } else {
                        $checked = 'checked="checked"';
                       // $clas = "disabled";
                    }
                    // $checked = isset($courses['adm'])!=0 ? 'checked="checked"' : '';

                    $output .= '  
                    <tr>  

                         <td>' . $i . '</td>  

                              <td>' . $courses['c_name'] . '</td> 
                                     <td><input type="text" id="txtFrom" /></td> 
                                             <td><input type="text" id="txtTo" /></td> 
                         <td><input name="checkbox[]"  id="d_checkbox'.$i.'"  class="checkbox1"  ' . $checked . ' type="checkbox" value="' . $courses['c_id'] . '"></td>          

                    </tr>  

                    ';
                    $i++;
                endforeach;







            $output .= "</table></div>";
            $output .= '<input type="hidden" name="c_id" value="' . $_REQUEST['courseid'] . '" id="c_id" /> ';


            echo $output;
        }
    }
```

which is call from ajax.here two date button

```
  <td><input type="text" id="txtFrom" /></td> 
                                                 <td><input type="text" id="txtTo" /></td>
```

view page:

```
`<form name="registration1_form" id="registration1_form" method="POST" action="<?php echo MANAGE_TEAM . 'addcoursetousers' ?>"` enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="modal-body" id="coursedetails">
```

**Table values Apprear here**

```
                    </div>  

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit"  name="submitabouc" id="i_submitdisc" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
```

script.js

```
$(function () { 
    $("#txtFrom").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function (selected) {
            var dt = new Date(selected);
            dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
            $("#txtTo").datepicker("option", "minDate", dt);
        }
    });
    $("#txtTo").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function (selected) {
            var dt = new Date(selected);
            dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - 1);
            $("#txtFrom").datepicker("option", "maxDate", dt);
        }
    });
});
```

but date function is not working.jquery datepicker is not working text box is present in controller PHP.i dont know why this happens..ANy help would be appreciated..

Comment: have you checked console?? any error?

Comment: @AkshitAhuja NO error

Comment: jquery files are loaded in correct serial? I mean jquery main file first and then after jquery-ui.js. Check this.

Comment: You haven't put the full relevant code in the question

Comment: You have put `<input type="text" id="txtFrom" />` inside a PHP foreach loop. This means you will potentially generate multiple copies of this input. However they will all have the same ID. This is not valid HTML. How is the JavaScript supposed to tell them apart? `$("#txtFrom")` will only ever select the first copy. It considers the rest not to be valid. Therefore your datepicker will only ever work on the first course. Use CSS classes instead of ids. Once you do that, you'll need a way to relate each "from" field to the correct "to" field. Perhaps a matching data-attribute would make sense.

Comment: Further, you mention that this PHP is called from AJAX. Therefore, at the time you run `$("#txtFrom").datepicker({`, your datepicker does not even exist yet. There is nothing for jQuery to attach the datepicker to - `$("#txtFrom")` will not match anything at that time. You need to attach the datepickers after the AJAX call is completed and you have added the HTML into the page.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for your correct my mistake

Comment: @ADyson i got it..thanks a lot